# Trying to convert CSV to Excel file in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have tried different codes and check online for the Solution. But not getting success in the below code.

```
df_new = pd.read_csv(path+'output.csv')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path+'output.xlsx')
df_new.to_excel(writer, index = False)
writer.save()
```

I am getting the below error when I am trying to execute it, I have try to add encoded as latin . But it is not working. Please guide me with it. When I am doing ignore_error it is running , but not providing any result.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Have you tried an other encoding? Add e.g. `encoding="ANSI"` to `read_csv`.

Comment: I have tried that as well, it is giving me below error. So, I have tried to avoid the `Header=None` and `skip the first row` also. But, till I am getting the error as below now: **'ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2'**